FFMPEG segment_times arg makes command too long
Context:
I have long video files (600+ hours) that I want to split on resolution change & keep the high-res parts. I have extracted all the timestamps to a file with ffprobe so now all that's left is to split the video.
The actual issue:
My FFMPEG commands have over 20k splits resulting in 300k character commands which bash complains about with 'argument list too long'
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c copy -segment_times 1799.68,1818.78,...,3283103.479 -reset_timestamps 1 -f segment output_%03d.mkv
Notes:

This command avoids re-encoding, making it significantly faster than other methods.
I need to maintain the ability to calculate the timestamp a clip came from.


have you looked at the docs for "preset files"? You might be able to put some of this into a preset file which would reduce the command line.

You'll have to perform this task in stages. Instead of creating all segments in one command, do it piecemeal.
Let's say you have 15 segment split points s1..s15.
ffmpeg -copyts -i input.mkv -map 0 -c copy -segment_times s1,s2,s3 -to s4 -segment_start_number 0 -reset_timestamps 0 -f segment out_%03d.mkv
ffmpeg -copyts -ss s4 -i input.mkv -map 0 -c copy -segment_times s5,s6,s7 -to s8 -segment_start_number 4 -reset_timestamps 0 -f segment out_%03d.mkv
ffmpeg -copyts -ss s8 -i input.mkv -map 0 -c copy -segment_times s9,s10,s11 -to s12 -segment_start_number 8 -reset_timestamps 0 -f segment out_%03d.mkv
ffmpeg -copyts -ss s12 -i input.mkv -map 0 -c copy -segment_times s13,s14,s15 -segment_start_number 12 -reset_timestamps 0 -f segment out_%03d.mkv

Thanks! I got my intended output by removing copyts, setting reset_timestamps to 1 and specifying timestamps relative to the one in the ss flag.
